# Error in Firefox while replace string using regexp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
try{    
  var hdnPassenger = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnPassenger").val(); 
  var newTr = $("#hdnCtl").html(); 
  newTr = newTr.replace(/_ID/g, hdnPassenger); 
}
catch(ex){
  alert(ex);
}
```

Above code is working fine in the internet explorer, but displayed the following error in the mozilla firefox

InternalError: regular expression too complex

Comment: InternalError: regular expression too complex

Comment: I guess, then next step is to find out what the value of `hdnPassenger` variable is.

Answer (score 0):

Having done some research into this problem, there are two possible reasons for this error:

1. The actual regex too complex (not in your case, as you only have /_ID/)
2. The length of the string you're trying to do the substitution on (I don't know what it is, but probably quite long).  It seems that there's some hard-coded limit in some versions of firefox, but I can't vouch for that.

I suggest you do two this: add the values of your `hdnPassenger` and `newTr` variables - and at the same time google `firefox regular expression too complex` - there are plenty of hits.